# Forcing first item in bootstrap 4 nav-pills to be full width when justified

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem when displaying nav-pills on mobile devices when I make it justified. For example, with the below code an iPhone displays the tabs justified but with the "It NavTab" pill on two lines. Is it possible to have the first nav-pill display at full width, and have the last two nav-pills justified underneath the first nav-pill? Please advise. Thanks!

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Hello!</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Testing!</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">It NavTab</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by setting the first `nav-item`'s width to 100% and resetting its `flex-basis` as `.nav-justified` sets the `flex-basis` of `nav-item`s to 0.

```
.nav-justified .nav-item .nav-link {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-justified .nav-item:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
}
```

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/75802/